# azure-cosmos-emulator on Linux with Cassandra API

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

Is there any way (and documentation) for running Azure Cosmos DB emulator on Linux with Cassandra API available?

I have been trying running it with docker-compose.yaml

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  db:
    container_name: cosmosdb
    image: "mcr.microsoft.com/cosmosdb/linux/azure-cosmos-emulator"
    tty: true
    restart: always
    mem_limit: 2G
    cpu_count: 2
    environment:
      - AZURE_COSMOS_EMULATOR_PARTITION_COUNT=10
      - AZURE_COSMOS_EMULATOR_ENABLE_DATA_PERSISTENCE=true
      - AZURE_COSMOS_EMULATOR_CASSANDRA_ENDPOINT=true
      - AZURE_COSMOS_EMULATOR_GREMLIN_ENDPOINT=true
    ports:
       - "8081:8081"
       - "8900:8900"
       - "8901:8901"
       - "8979:8979"
       - "10250:10250"
       - "10251:10251"
       - "10252:10252"
       - "10253:10253"
       - "10254:10254"
       - "10255:10255"
       - "10256:10256"
       - "10350:10350"
    volumes:
       - vol_cosmos:/data/db

volumes:
  vol_cosmos:
```

But port 10350 is not used in container and nothing is listening there.

Is there any documented way how to run Cassandra API (and MongoDb as well) with linux container?

Thanks

Comment: ["Currently, the Linux emulator only supports SQL API."](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/linux-emulator?tabs=ssl-netstd21)

Comment: Is there any roadmap or planned feature set so we can track which features are going to be available and when?

Comment: @MartinMacak - unfortunately, roadmaps would be off-topic here - that is a support-specific question, and you would need to look to official support channels.

Comment: There is no ETA for Cassandra support for Linux emulator. Closest thing I can suggest is to download from here (3.11 version) and run locally. https://cassandra.apache.org/_/download.html